# TypeError when querying dataframe with field condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make the following query:

`df7[df7['bath'] > 10]`

But I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'`

[Here is an image of my environment with the dataframe and error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFGrk.png)

Comment: What is the dtype of bath? `df7['bath'].dtype`

Comment: What is the output of `df7.loc[pd.to_numeric(df7['bath'], errors='coerce').isna(), 'bath'].unique()`?

Answer (score 1):

`df7[df7['bath'] > 10]` is the correct command *if* your column name is "bath" and its *dtype* is *float*.

You could check the *dtype* of the columns in your dataframe (making sure it's not *object* or some other datatype) by printing `df7.dtypes`

You could also confirm the names of your columns by printing `df7.columns` to ensure that the column name is indeed "bath" and not " bath" or "bath " (note the extra spaces). It's hard to tell that from the attached screenshot.

Do update if it works for you, or if you run into more errors.